# When I click on react router nothing happen

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, react-router

I am working on a list of pokemons app like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XehSJF85F38&t=5904s

But I have problem, for some reason my routes don't work, and I did everything like in tutorial.
Here is my code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"></Route>
            <Route exact path="pokemon/:pokemonIndex" component={Pokemon} />
          </Switch>
          <Body />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And I call it in another component:

```
render() {
return (
  <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
    <Link to={`pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`} className="cardLink">
      <div className="card cardeffect">
        <h5 className="card-header">
          {this.state.pokemonIndex}. {this.state.pokemonName.toUpperCase()}
        </h5>
        {this.state.imageLoading ? (
          <img
            src={loading}
            style={{ width: "6em", height: "6em" }}
            className="card-img-top mx-auto mt-2"
          />
        ) : null}
        <div className="card-body mx-auto">
          <Sprite
            className="card-image-top mx-auto mt-2"
            onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
            onError={() => this.setState({ request: true })}
            src={this.state.imageUrl}
            style={
              this.state.tooManyRequest
                ? { display: "none" }
                : this.state.imageLoading
                ? { display: "none" }
                : { display: "block" }
            }
          ></Sprite>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

}

But when I click on any of cards, URL changes but that is all, nothing more happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ey!

I am not sure but I think Link is not fitted for what you want to do. It's ok to create a link on a navbaritem for instance but not to trigger redirection onclick.

Maybe try to use an onclick event on your card with the `Redirect` [component](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect). Something like this might work:

```
<div className="card-body mx-auto" onclick={() => {return <Redirect to=`pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`}>
      <Sprite
        className="card-image-top mx-auto mt-2"
        onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
        onError={() => this.setState({ request: true })}
        src={this.state.imageUrl}
        style={
          this.state.tooManyRequest
            ? { display: "none" }
            : this.state.imageLoading
            ? { display: "none" }
            : { display: "block" }
        }
      >
     </Sprite>
    </div>
```

You might also be able to trigger the event directly in the Sprite component, Idk this package.

Hopping it will help !

Answer (score 0):

It will be useful for you to do this from the root while defining the route.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"></Route>
            <Route path="/pokemon/:pokemonIndex" component={Pokemon} />
          </Switch>
          <Body />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

and

```js
render() {
return (
  <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-3">
    <Link to={`/pokemon/${this.state.pokemonIndex}`} className="cardLink">
      ...
      ...
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```